# PHP Contact Form: empty values received, no update to div for delivery success message

Tags: php, html

My question might be quite a simple one, but I am very new to PHP and have tried to piece everything together after reading, but have run into some problems. I have read through possible duplicates of this post and tried as much as possible to put those solutions into my code but to no avail.

Objective:

1. Name and email validation (just not empty and in email format)
2. Details sent to indicated email
3. Basic sanitizing of code (mysqli escape and htmlspecialchars) (Understand that there is PDO, but would like to stick to this).
4. After successful submission, reload page with same website (fields empty) but with message in  indicating message sent or error. Am trying header("Location: "). Would prefer not to introduce AJAX as I have no knowledge of it. Is this possible? Have also read about using action:"" to stay on same page, but how do I run my mail.php if my action is ""? Have also tried include: mail.php, or renaming my mail.php to index.php, but still did not succeed.

Current problems faced:

1. I do receive an email but with empty fields, i.e. inputs are not reflected although I did enter some values in the form. These are the values I received:

From:

Phone:

etc....

2. Page does direct to header location. But div not updated with $success variable, i.e. no message updated to show in div.

Please refer to my php and html file below:
PHP:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "dbname");

$NameErr=$EmailErr=$Success="";
$Name=$Email=$Company=$JobTitle=$Phone=$Message="";

function sanitize($link,$entry) {
    $entry = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$entry);
    $entry = htmlspecialchars($entry);

    return $entry;
}

if (empty($_POST["Name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
    } 
    else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/", $Name)) {
      $NameErr = "Only letters and spaces allowed"; 
    }
    else {
    $Name = sanitize($link, $_POST["Name"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["Email"])) {
    $EmailErr = "Email is required";
    }  
    else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $EmailErr = "Invalid email format";
    }
    else {
    $Email = sanitize($link, $_POST["Email"]); 
}

$Company = sanitize($link, $_POST["Company"]);
$JobTitle = sanitize($link, $_POST["JobTitle"]);
$Phone = sanitize($link, $_POST["Phone"]);
$Message = sanitize($link, $_POST["Message"]);
$formcontent=" From: $Name \n Phone: $Phone \n Company: $Company \n Job Title: $JobTitle \n Phone: $Phone \n Message: $Message";
$recipient = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $Email \r\n";
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)){
        $Success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
        header("location:Contact.Us.html");
    }
    else($Success = "Sorry, we are unable to process your submission.");
?>
```

HTML form:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
            <ul class="contact">
                <li>
                <label for="Name">Name<span class="red">*</span></label>
                <p><input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" required/></p>

                </li>
                <li>
                <label for="Email">Email<span class="red">*</span></label>
                <p><input id="Email" name="Email" type="email" required/></p>
                </li>

                <li>
                <label for="Company">Company</label>
                <p><input id="Company" name="Company"/></p>
                </li>

                <li>
                <label for="JobTitle">Job Title</label>
                <p><input id="JobTitle" name="JobTitle"/></p>
                </li>

                <li>
                <label for="Phone">Phone</label>
                <p><input id="Phone" name="Phone"/></p>
                </li>

                <li>
                <label for="Message">Message</label>
                <p><textarea id="Message" wrap="soft" name="Message"></textarea></p>
                </li>

            </ul>
            <br>
            <p><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send!" /></p>
            <div class="success"><? =$Success; ?></div>
        </form>
```

Would appreciate your reply to resolve any of the problems mentioned above. Would also appreciate if you could highlight other areas of possible security concerns. Thanks!

Also, upon implementing recommendation of sanitize($link,$entry), I am receiving inputs in my email for the variables: Company and Job Title.

Hence, I further changed all my variables name to first letter capital i.e. $message to $Message and aligned it throughout my form's input 'id', 'name' and 'for'. After which, I managed to receive input for the additional variables of Phone and Message.

Currently, am only not receiving values in my email for variables Name and Email. Perhaps there is an error with my 'if else if' portion of the php code. Will figure and update again. In the meantime, if any recommendation, please continue to update too. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It would be nice to see what it was that you tried in order to have resolved this yourself, which would have shown us that you did research this before posting the question. 
When you try, you also learn. If someone just gives you an answer/solution, it would have all been for nothing and I say this for the/your future. 
You can then edit your post to contain something that may have failed; even that shows an effort on your part. Remember, we're always glad to help.

Comment: your error  on the function sanitize($entry) change $entry = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$entry);

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- for the advice. Have edited my question after implementing the recommendations here and did some further edits. So sorry still learning how things work on this website too as this is my first post! :)

Comment: Thanks @headmax for the recommendation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @headmax pointed,  you need to also pass the link parameter to the sanitize function

```
function sanitize ($link,  $entry) {

}
```

Reason is without passing it as a parameter,  the $link variable becomes undefined. If you had error reporting on,  you would have gotten a notice on $link.

For future purposes, whenever in development environment, always turn on error reporting as

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);//place this at the top of the script
```

EDIT

In order for you to display the success message and perform a redirect, you'd be better off using Ajax.

```
setTimeOut();//use this to display the success message for a while(pass number of seconds)
```

Then perform a redirect using javascript as

```
window.location.href ='URL';
```

Using your approach, just declare the success variable as

```
$success = '';//add this before you use the variable
```

Comment: Thanks @Akintunde and headmax for your help. As updated it did help out with my contact form, but there are still some problems unresolved. Also, I have previously declared the success variable all the way at the top of the php. i.e. $NameErr=$EmailErr=$Success=""; Will also check out the error reporting function! Thanks!